# Ef core : Filter out an item from a list of a list

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.1

I have this kind of model

```
public class Blog
{
   public IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
   public PostType PostType { get; set; }
}

public class PostType
{
   public string Code { get; set; } // "Code1" and "Code2"
}
```

What I want is, to return all Blogs with a post of PostType **Code1** or a Blog with no post(assuming a blog may not have a post)

To do that, I wrote this Ef linq query:

```
_dbContext.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts).ThenInclude(b => b.PostType)
    .Where(b => b.Posts.Count == 0 || b.Posts.Any(p => p.PostType.Code == "Code1").ToList();
```

The problem with this query is; if the blog has posts with types **Code1** and **Code2**, the above query includes both Posts of code **Code2** and **Code1** because I'm using *Any*.

So I tried this: instead of *Any*, I used *All*

```
_dbContext.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts).ThenInclude(b => b.PostType)
    .Where(b => b.Posts.Count == 0 || b.Posts.All(p => p.PostType.Code == "Code1").ToList();
```

But with the above scenario, this query returns nothing.

With the given situation, is there a way to return all blogs with a post of post type **Code1**, without including post type **Code2** using **a single** Ef LINQ query?

**EDITED:**
Found this blog... https://entityframework.net/include-with-where-clause

**UPDATED**

This feature is now available on .net EF core 5 [Filtered Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include)

Comment: A Blog in your model does not have a PostType, but a list of Posts that each have a PostType. So do you want to return all Blogs that have any Post with PostType Code1, or Blogs with their Posts, but only the Posts that are PostType Code1?

Comment: There is something not clear about your question. A blog can contain posts of both types? So, if one blog has both types, do you want it to return or no? And if yes, do you want it to return all posts or the ones of specific type. It seems to me you need two queries, one to get all the blogs containing any mix. The second, to filter out only posts of certain type from the first query.

Comment: @AsheraH I want to return all Blogs with a list of Posts of type Code1.

Comment: Would it not be simpler to just get all the blogs with all their posts, where code != Code2?

Comment: @Archer to do that you have to use Any... right? Still the same result will come up

Comment: I guess I must be missing something, as this just seems like a simple filter to me - return all blogs, but only include posts where PostType.Code == "Code1".

Answer (score 2):

The solution is like Thierry V's one, except for storing the filtered posts in a separate dictionary to avoid EF tracking side-effects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking.

However, I cannot really see the reason behind such code. Normally, you would grab all the blogs that satisfy your condition (containing any post of Code1), and then filter them as needed.

```
var blogs = _dbContext.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts).ThenInclude(b => b.PostType)
    .Where(b => b.Posts.Count == 0 || b.Posts.Any(p => p.PostType.Code == "Code1")
    .ToList(); 

// Storing the filterd posts in a dictionary to avoid side-effects of EF tracking.
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<Post>>();
foreach (var blog in blogs) {
    dictionary[blog.BlogId] = blog.Posts.Where(p => p.PostType.Code == "Code1").ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var blogs = _dbContext.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts).ThenInclude(b => b.PostType)
    .Where(b => b.Posts.Count == 0 || b.Posts.Any(p => p.PostType.Code == "Code1").ToList(); 
// blogs contains posts which have Code1, and maybe Code2

//filter the posts by assigning only the posts with Code1
blogs.ForEach(b=> b.Posts = b.Posts.Where( p => p.PostType.Code == "Code1"))
```